# Opening a report based on combo box input

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Access newbie here. I have an unbound form with a ComboBox `cmb_SelProdName` bound to `AlloyName` of my MDB. The user selects an Alloy Name from the box, and a Form button On Click event does a DoCmd.OpenReport which should pass the AlloyName to the report "rpt_xTest":

`DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_xTest", acViewReport, , , , OpenArgs:=Me.cmb_SelProdName`

On the (unbound) report is a bound text box with `=[Forms]![OpenArgs]` which should display the value in the combobox.

What happens is, I select the alloy I want, press the button, and immediately get a dialogue asking for "Sample Name". When I type anything, I go to my blank report with #Error in my text box.

I'm stuck at this point and desperate for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text box displays `#Error` because `[Forms]![OpenArgs]` means a form object named *OpenArgs* which is currently open in Form View.

But I think you actually want the value of the *OpenArgs **option*** which was supplied with `DoCmd.OpenReport`.  If that is correct, use this as the Control Source property for your text box:

```vb
=[OpenArgs]
```

I tested that with for a report text box with Access 2007.